# SQL to MDX Query Parameter Error expected ')'

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, report, mdx

Can you help me fix the mdx code according to SQL Declare.
The error that is showing is BC30198 expected ')' and i dont know why.
Here the objective is get the data of the report, if is day 1 of the current month it has to give me last month in full, if it´s last day 1 of the current year it has to show me only the data from current month from day 1.
Can you help me with the error or give me another way to get what i want from the report?

The code is below.

Thank ou guys

SQL:

```
declare @anomes int
set @anomes = IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1, YEAR(GETDATE()-1)*100 + month (getdate()-1), YEAR(GETDATE())*100 + month (getdate()))
```

mdx ssrs:

```
=iif(
datepart("m",Today()) = 1, 
datepart("y", DateAdd("d", -1, Today()))*100 + datepart("m", DateAdd("d", -1, Today())), 
datepart("y", Today())*100 + datepart("m", Today()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a few issues, although it's hard to tell as it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Firstly, you SSRS expression is missing a closing parenthesis on the 4th line (after `Today()`)

It looks like you are just trying to get the current month as an integer unless its January in which case you want December of the previous year, so in Jan 2022 you want to get 202112 back and in May 2022 you want to get 202205.

If this is not correct, **edit your question** and explain with a couple of examples, the results you would expect to get.

If my assumption is correct then your SQL statement could be something like this (I've used a variable so you can test with various dates)

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = GETDATE()
SELECT CAST(format(dateadd("m", IIF(MONTH(@dt) = 1, -1, 0), @dt), 'yyyyMM') as int)
```

In SSRS the expression is almost identical

```
=CINT(FORMAT(DateAdd("m", IIF(Month(Today()) = 1, - 1, 0), Today()), "yyyyMM"))
```

Obviously you can remove the CINT and CAST(*n* as INT) is you only need a string.

---

**Update based on response from OP**

---

The easiest way would probably be to just do this in your dataset query, As you have not shown that, this will be a generic answer.

In this example, I used a variable `@cDate` for testing, you can swap this out for `GetDate()` or whatever suits your purpose. This script works out the start and end dates and then there is a sample `SELECT` statement at the end using the results. If this is in yuor dataset query, you will only get back the rows within the correct date range. Much easier than trying to do this in SSRS (IMHO).

```
declare @cdate date = '2022-05-20' -- swap for GetDate() in production
declare @sdate date
declare @edate date

IF day(@cdate) = 1
    BEGIN 
        SET @sdate = DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(@cdate, -2)) 
        SET @edate = EOMONTH(@cdate, -1)    
    END 
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @sdate = DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(@cdate, -1)) 
        SET @edate = EOMONTH(@cdate)    
    END 
-- test the output
SELECT @cdate as CurrentDate, @sdate as Startdate, @edate as EndDate

-- sample SELETC statement
-- SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateColumn BETWEEN @sdate AND @edate
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, what i want is when i get the report on 1st day of the month to give me the data from the previous month and if it´s not day 1 of the current month (ex: day 2, or forward) it gives me the data from the current month till the day im getting the report

Comment: Thnak you so much for your hel. It worked

Comment: No problem. If the answered your question then please mark the answer as accepted. It's the check mark under the vote up/down buttons to the left. Thus helps others find answers to similar questions